# CMake in macOS, precompiled header files (.pch) support

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cmake, clang

I was thinking about moving my project compilation from the cumbersome Xcode into the convenient environment of CMake.

However, I wasn't able to find cmake support for precompiled header files (.pch) in macOS that mimic the Xcode flow.

In Xcode, the first stage is `ProcessPCH` where the pch file compile is compiled as standalone file according to the source code language (my project contains `m` `mm` and `cpp` files)

I.E :

```
1. objective-c(.m): `-x objective-c-header` 
2. objective-c++(.mm): `-x objective-c++-header` 
3. c++(.cpp): `-x c++-header`
...
```

and the result is binary Macho target with suffix `.pch.pch`.

Then, in order to precompile the pch with every source file in the project  the following flag is added to the compilation command `-include <pch_output_file_from_the_previous_stage>`

Is there any way to do so in CMake ? are there any equivalent alternatives ?

EDIT:

I revealed that it was once possible to set up precompiled headers for macOS project with regular `.h` file and GCC compiler, but I haven't found the corresponding flags for `clang/clang++` which are now used by Xcode

```
set_target_properties(
    executable
    PROPERTIES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PREFIX_HEADER "path/stdwx.h"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER "YES"
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using pre-compiled headers with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148570/using-pre-compiled-headers-with-cmake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake has just gained support for PCHs, it should be available in the upcoming 3.16 release, due 2019-10-01:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/3553

```
  target_precompile_headers(<target>
    <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [header1...]
    [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [header2...] ...])
```

There is ongoing discussion on supporting sharing PCHs between targets: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19659

This includes support for xcode generator too.