# CMake how to group generated precompiled headers in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

When I use `target_precompile_headers()` in visual studio I will get the following structure:

```
+-- Precompile Header File
|  |
|  +-- cmake_pch.hxx
|  +-- cmake_pch.hxx
|  +-- cmake_pch.hxx
|  +-- cmake_pch.hxx
+-- Source Files
|  | 
|  +-- cmake_pch.cxx
```

Calling `source_group()` after this method doesn't work. How do I group these files together?

Comment: Another example for not using precompiled headers:  they are a pain to maintain (and add time to your build because they may need to be rebuilt).

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? The CMake filters for these really bug me out as well...

Comment: @GregorSattel Im using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/260367/5506840)

Answer (score 0):

For example you can make:

```
source_group("Generated Files" FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/${PROJECT_NAME}.dir/cmake_pch.cxx)
foreach(config_type ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
    source_group("Generated Files" FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/${PROJECT_NAME}.dir/${config_type}/cmake_pch.hxx)
endforeach()
```

There is no cmake variable than contains the path to `CMakeFiles/${PROJECT_NAME}.dir`, hence the above usage rather is a hack.

The result:

```
Generated Files
|
+-- cmake_pch.cxx
+-- cmake_pch.hxx
+-- cmake_pch.hxx
+-- cmake_pch.hxx
+-- cmake_pch.hxx
```